# Question for my linked list code, odd bug

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a problem with this code, I don't know why it stops looping the second switch(input) after inputing the datas 3 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    char Name[50];
    int value; 
    Node *next, *prev; 
}*head, *tail;


Node* createNode(int value, char name[]){
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    strcpy(newNode->Name, name);
    newNode->value = value; 
    return newNode; 
}


void pushTail(int value, char name[]){
    Node *newNode = createNode(value, name);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = tail = newNode; 
        return; 
    }
    else{
       tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = tail; 
        tail = newNode;     
    }
}

void makelongList(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}

void orderHistory(int val){
    Node* curr = head; 
    makelongList();
    printf("=== Order History ===\n");
    int i = 0;
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("Order %d : %s, %d pcs\n", i+1, curr->Name, curr->value);    
        i++;
        curr = curr->next; 
    }
    printf("Total Spent = Rp. %d \n", val);
    printf("=====================\n"); getchar();

}

void itemDatabase(){
    makelongList();
    printf("=========================================\n");
    printf("| Item Code |    Item Name   |  Price   |\n");
    printf("=========================================\n"); 
    printf("|    A0     | Milk Tea       | Rp. 3000 |\n");
    printf("|    A1     | Mineral Water  | Rp. 2000 |\n");
    printf("|    A2     | Hot Dog        | Rp. 7000 |\n");
    printf("|    A3     | Cheeseburger   | Rp. 9000 |\n");
    printf("|    A4     | Cold/Hot Tea   | Rp. 4000 |\n");
    printf("=========================================\n");
    
    printf("\n Press enter to continue\n");  getchar(); 
}

void printMenu(){
    printf("=== suniB Supermarket ===\n");
    printf("1. View Available Items\n"); 
    printf("2. Buy Items\n");
    printf("3. Order History\n"); 
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("=========================\n");
    printf(">> "); 
}

void printReciept(int val){
    printf("=== suniB Supermarket ===\n"); 
    printf("=  -  R E C I E P T - ===\n  ");
    printf("      [Name]-[QTY] \n");
    Node *curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
    printf("        %s     %d \n", curr->Name, curr->value);
        curr = curr->next; 
    }
    printf("Total Spent = Rp. %d \n", val);
    printf("-Thank You For Shopping!-\n"); 
    printf("=========================\n");
}
void classicprintList(){
    Node *curr = head; 
    printf("NULL");
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("<-[ %d ]->", curr->value);
        curr = curr->next; 
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(){
    
    int input, qty, pricelist[10] = {3000, 2000, 7000, 9000, 4000}, mult = 0, total = 0, temps = 0;
    char itemcode[2], temp[2] = {0}, optionstring[2]; 
    
    do{
        makelongList(); 
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d", &input); getchar();
        switch(input){
            case 1: 
                itemDatabase(); 
                break; 
            case 2: 
                do{
                    do{
                        printf("Insert the item code you want to buy : "); scanf("%s", itemcode); getchar(); 
                    }while((itemcode[0] != 'A') && (itemcode[1] != '0') && (itemcode[1] != '1') && (itemcode[1] != '2') && (itemcode[1] != '3') && (itemcode[1] != '4'));
                    do{
                        printf("Insert the amount : "); scanf("%d", &qty); getchar(); 
                    }while(qty < 0);
                    temp[0] = itemcode[1];
                    temps = atoi(temp); 
                    switch(temps){
                        case 0:
                            mult = qty*pricelist[0];
                            total += mult; 
                            printf("\nItem name : Milk Tea\n");
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            mult = qty*pricelist[1]; 
                            total += mult;
                            printf("\nItem name : Mineral Water\n"); 
                            break; 
                        case 2: 
                            mult = qty*pricelist[2]; 
                            total += mult; 
                            printf("\nItem name : Hot Dog\n"); 
                            break; 
                        case 3:
                            mult = qty*pricelist[3]; 
                            total += mult; 
                            printf("\nItem name : Cheeseburger\n");
                            break; 
                        case 4:
                            mult = qty*pricelist[4];
                            total += mult; 
                            printf("\nItem name : Cold | Hot Tea\n"); 
                            break; 
                    }
                    printf("Your total amount will be : %d\n", total);
                    printf("Do you want to continue? [Y | N]? : "); scanf("%c", optionstring); getchar(); 
                    pushTail(qty, itemcode); 
                }while(strcmp(optionstring, "Y") == 0);
                break;
            case 3:
                orderHistory(total); 
                break; 
            case 4:
                break; 
        }
        
    }while(input >= 1 && input <= 4);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

the program returns value 3221226356 after the third loop of case 2. If anyone could help it would be amazing.

I expect the loop to keep going and input as many datas possible. Would say at least it could loop 10 times, but the more the better.

Comment: Please reduce it to [mcve].

Comment: `createNode` doesn't set `newNode->next` and `newNode->prev` to `NULL`. So your loop doesn't stop when it gets to the end of the list.

Comment: If you don't check the return value from `scanf`, you cannot possibly know what is happening.  Always, always, *always* check the return value.  eg `if( scanf("%d", ...) != 1 ){ /* scanf did not read a value; program must handle this case */ }`

Comment: I tried adding the newNode->next and the newNode->prev, so far it didn't change anything, I am pretty confused

Comment: You've got multiple instances of `getchar()` where it seems you are assuming you will read a newline.  You should verify those.  The `scanf("%c")` is almost certainly not reading what you expect, and may be unexpectedly consuming a newline.  You need to clean up the way you are reading input and validate your expectations.

Comment: ah ok, I'll try to fix it first, this is my second semester work and just started data structures and it is kinda mind bending at first

Comment: A bit late but I found the fix, it turns out that at the "malloc(sizeof(Node*));" there shouldn't be a pointer after the node, anyways thanks for the help on the other portions

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the list has undefined behavior because data members `next` and `prev` are not initialized in nodes added to the list

```
Node* createNode(int value, char name[]){
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    strcpy(newNode->Name, name);
    newNode->value = value; 
    return newNode; 
}


void pushTail(int value, char name[]){
    Node *newNode = createNode(value, name);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = tail = newNode; 
        return; 
    }
    else{
       tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = tail; 
        tail = newNode;     
    }
}
```

Also there are other problems.

For example in this do while statement with an awful long condition

```
do{
    printf("Insert the item code you want to buy : "); scanf("%s", itemcode); getchar(); 
}while((itemcode[0] != 'A') && (itemcode[1] != '0') && (itemcode[1] != '1') && (itemcode[1] != '2') && (itemcode[1] != '3') && (itemcode[1] != '4'));
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array `itemcode` in call of `scanf` because the array declared with 2 elements can store only one character apart from the terminating zero character `'\0'`. So such expressions like for example that

```
(itemcode[1] != '1')
```

do not make sense.